# Create Cronjob for wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cron

I have created a plugin to import products to WooCommerce, what I want to do now is create a cronjob for it. But all that I have tried does not work. This is the code I used:

```
function empty_product_table_function() {
$table_name='products';
$truncatetable=$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("TRUNCATE TABLE $table_name"));
wp_mail( 'shop@domain.com', 'Shop Cron', 'The Cron started' );
}
if($truncatetable !== FALSE)
{
   echo("All rows have been deleted.");
}
else
{
   echo("No rows have been deleted.");
}
```

from there I created a cron in wp control but still noting i used this totorial to create it
[Cloudways](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/wordpress-cron-job/)

can someone point me in the right direction

Comment: You didn't show us the code that defines the [hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/scheduling-wp-cron-events/#adding-the-hook) you use to run your cron code. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: You should use **[Action Scheduler](https://wordpress.org/plugins/action-scheduler/)** plugin, that is a scalable, traceable job queue for background processing… 
Note that [Action Scheduler library](https://github.com/woocommerce/action-scheduler) is included / used by WooCommerce, WooCommerce Subscriptions and some other plugins, a much better alternative to WP Cron… 
The documentations with code example is on [ActionScheduler.org](https://actionscheduler.org/)

Answer (score -1):

Define the Cron Function:
Ensure that your cron function (empty_product_table_function) is declared within your plugin.

Trigger the Function:
Make sure this function is being called at the right time. Cron jobs in WordPress are generally scheduled using the wp_schedule_event function.

```
// Schedule the event
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'empty_product_table_cron' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'empty_product_table_cron' );
}

// Hook the function to the scheduled event
add_action( 'empty_product_table_cron', 'empty_product_table_function' );
```

This code should be placed in your plugin file, ideally in a place where it gets executed (like the main plugin file or a dedicated initialization file).